# How to check my quota from terminal using LDAP

Tags: bash, ldap

We are using a (synology) fileserver in combination with LDAP to host all the home directories for our users. Every user gets assigned a certain quota of how many GB he is allowed to use in his home directory.

Is there a way to check how large the quota is allowed by the LDAP fileserver?
Something equivalent to

```
df -h
```

for local partitions

Comment: "Every user gets assigned a certain quota" sure but that has no relation with ldap? I would assume the relation here is the `quota` command?!

Answer (score 0):

You question is not completely clear to me but the generic method to view a users quota on a Linux system would be with:

```
quota -u $USER
```

If you use samba and NTFS shares you can also use

```
smbcquotas -u $USER
```

from the users side.

But both are not related to LDAP: LDAP is a directory access protocol; Quotas are not a part of that but can be a part of the total setup if you include samba or the native quota tools on Ubuntu.

Comment: The `quota` command outputs nothing and the `smbcquotas` command does not exist, also there wasn't any ubuntu package with the same name installable via apt-get

Comment: Then I would assume your problem is on the server where LDAP is active (what is running there?) and not on the Ubuntu server. Or that it is part of software used on the fileserver (ie. a 3rd party tool that is not using the native Linux tools).

Comment: That might be. The Server is from synology and their operating system is called `DiskStation Manager` which apparantly is Linux based.

Comment: So you dont know if this is Ubuntu related?

Comment: Well, good question. I'm using Ubuntu 16.04. However since LDAP is provided by some fileserver, it might also be an issue of the fileserver or LDAP. I guess the question is if LDAP is equiped with some means of checking the quota.

Comment: You will need to ask the person that installed the server. synology servers are bought without OS but does include a virtualization manager where you install 1 or more operatings system. It could be Fedora, Suse, Yellowdog, and even Windows. Plus it is totally possible that quota's are regulated through DiskStation Manager and that that software has its own commands you can use.